# Removing background from .GIF image

Tags: adobe-photoshop, background-removal

Original Image:

[image]

My try:

[image]

This is the image. I tried using `Polygonal Lasso Tool`, but the edges don't appear to be OK.

Is there more precise way to remove the background and leave the letters and the logo icon on a transparent background?

Comment: It would be easier to recreate that image than it would be to remove the drop shadow.

Comment: Hey, I found a solution. I make a background `#000000`, then select the same color as foreground color -> Color Range. And it selects everything and I just press delete. :)

Comment: The typeface is basically Avenir book with some slight adjustment to the hook of the G. http://i.stack.imgur.com/f5qAW.png

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue you are faced here is a limitation of the GIF transparency which is limited to a single color from the palette. Semi-transparent colors are not possible.

[image]
<sup>"Transparency" of the original GIF file</sup>

To obtain an image with a transparent background but with keeping the shadows we can take the following steps (below done with GIMP but any other image processing application including Photoshop should be able to do this)

2. Convert the image from indexed to RGB
3. Remove the transparency alpha channel

   [image]
   <sup>Alpha channel removed and replaced by white</sup>
4. Replace white with an alpha channel

   [image]
   <sup>White replaced by transparency</sup>
5. Save in an image format supporting semi-transparent colors (here .png)

   [image]

This will then lead to the desired transparency as seen below:

[image]
<sup>Transparent image on coloured background</sup>

Note that in the case here where the Image had grey scales not only in the shadows but also in the letters all these shades of grey will also have some transparency from the white alpha channel. This may in some cases not be wanted. We then will have to recreate the image.